# RuntimeError: mat1 dim 1 must match mat2 dim 0 Pytorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I am trying to evaluate my model on random weight and bias before training by calling the  `evaluate(model, valid_dl)` but I get the below error.

I have also tried debugging my code by the printing the size of tensor after taking a step by step walk through on my error traceback.

I have also check similar problem on SO but the solutions are not working for me.

I think the error is coming from `self.classifier`. it appear there is something I am not getting right there. Please I need your help .

**Error traceback**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-1c4791c5f87e> in <module>
----> 1 history = [evaluate(model, valid_dl)]
      2 history

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/autograd/grad_mode.py in decorate_context(*args, **kwargs)
     24         def decorate_context(*args, **kwargs):
     25             with self.__class__():
---> 26                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
     27         return cast(F, decorate_context)
     28 

<ipython-input-30-b49ebc28d6a3> in evaluate(model, val_loader)
      2 def evaluate(model, val_loader):
      3     model.eval()
----> 4     outputs = [model.validation_step(batch) for batch in val_loader]
      5     return model.validation_epoch_end(outputs)
      6 

<ipython-input-30-b49ebc28d6a3> in <listcomp>(.0)
      2 def evaluate(model, val_loader):
      3     model.eval()
----> 4     outputs = [model.validation_step(batch) for batch in val_loader]
      5     return model.validation_epoch_end(outputs)
      6 

<ipython-input-23-e9609521578c> in validation_step(self, batch)
     12     def validation_step(self, batch):
     13         images, labels = batch
---> 14         out = self(images)                   # Generate predictions
     15         loss = F.cross_entropy(out, labels)   # Calculate loss
     16         acc = accuracy(out, labels)           # Calculate accuracy

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    725             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    726         else:
--> 727             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    728         for hook in itertools.chain(
    729                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

<ipython-input-28-3b2b2b49d22e> in forward(self, xb)
     34         print(out.shape)
     35 
---> 36         out = self.classifier(out)
     37         print(out.shape)
     38         return out

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    725             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    726         else:
--> 727             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    728         for hook in itertools.chain(
    729                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py in forward(self, input)
    115     def forward(self, input):
    116         for module in self:
--> 117             input = module(input)
    118         return input
    119 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    725             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    726         else:
--> 727             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    728         for hook in itertools.chain(
    729                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py in forward(self, input)
     91 
     92     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
---> 93         return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
     94 
     95     def extra_repr(self) -> str:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in linear(input, weight, bias)
   1688     if input.dim() == 2 and bias is not None:
   1689         # fused op is marginally faster
-> 1690         ret = torch.addmm(bias, input, weight.t())
   1691     else:
   1692         output = input.matmul(weight.t())

RuntimeError: mat1 dim 1 must match mat2 dim 0
```

Model

```
def conv_block(in_channels, out_channels, pool=False):
    layers = [nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1), 
              nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels), 
              nn.ReLU(inplace=True)]
    if pool: layers.append(nn.MaxPool2d(2))
    return nn.Sequential(*layers)

class ResNet9(ImageClassificationBase):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, num_classes):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.conv1 = conv_block(in_channels, 64)
        self.conv2 = conv_block(64, 128, pool=True)
        self.res1 = nn.Sequential(conv_block(128, 128), conv_block(128, 128))
        
        self.conv3 = conv_block(128, 256, pool=True)
        self.conv4 = conv_block(256, 512, pool=True)
        self.res2 = nn.Sequential(conv_block(512, 512), conv_block(512, 512))
        
        self.classifier = nn.Sequential(nn.MaxPool2d(4), 
                                        nn.Flatten(), 
                                        nn.Dropout(0.2),
                                        nn.Linear(512, num_classes))
        
    def forward(self, xb):
        out = self.conv1(xb)
        print(out.shape)
        out = self.conv2(out)
        print(out.shape)
        out = self.res1(out) + out
        print(out.shape)
        out = self.conv3(out)
        print(out.shape)
        out = self.conv4(out)
        print(out.shape)
        out = self.res2(out) + out 
        print(out.shape)       
        out = self.classifier(out)
        #Error
        print(out.shape)
        
        return out
enter code here
```

Output shapes from the forward pass

```
torch.Size([32, 64, 400, 400])
torch.Size([32, 128, 200, 200])
torch.Size([32, 128, 200, 200])
torch.Size([32, 256, 100, 100])
torch.Size([32, 512, 50, 50])
torch.Size([32, 512, 50, 50])
```

but when I check the shape after `self.classifier` I get am error

Comment: Could you give the input shape as well as the code you used to call your model in eval mode?

Comment: @Ivan my input shape is `torch.Size([32, 3, 400, 400])` and I used this code to call my model `evaluate(model, valid_dl)`

Comment: Your tensor shape just before the last `nn.Linear` is `(batch_size, 73728)` and you are feeding it to a dense layer that only has *512* input features.

Comment: @Ivan how were you able to come up with the 73728 value..?

Comment: Just pull out `nn.Linear(512, num_classes)` and look at your output shape.

Comment: @Ivan you are right, I pulled out the Linear and the final Maxpool and I am getting a weird output. what could be the possible reason for this..?

Comment: There's nothing weird about it, it's just your model's architecture. You should probably modify it since *73728* seems unreasonable for classifier dense layer. Where did you find this particular version of Resnet?

Comment: @Ivan I think the error is coming from the `self.classifier` , I just checked it out

Comment: Of course it comes from the classifier: as you saw the output just before the `nn.Linear` is `(batch_size, 73728)`, and your linear layer only expects *512* features.